# change content between tags in html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

**cant change a content using textContent property in js for a (a) tag in html**

so i have this code in my first html page

```
<li><a name="regbutton" href="loginReg.html">Register</a></li>
```

and this code in my second html page

```
<button type="button" id="regDirect" onclick="register()">
```

so i wanted to change "register" to a name value , Here is Js function

```
function register() {
  let name = document.getElementById("RegisterForm").value; //get name from form in second html page
  document.getElementsByName("regbutton").textContent = name; 
  window.location.href = "index.html"; // redirect to first page
}
```

but the button ( id = regDirect ) dont work when this line in JavaScript is present

```
document.getElementsByName("regbutton").textContent = name;
```

if i deleted this line the redirect works but value ( register ) doesnt change

Comment: getElement**s**ByName is an HTML collection..... You can not change anything on another page when you have not had it loaded....

Answer (score 1):

To put it simply, you won't be able to do what you set out to do with these tools. You can only access the currently loaded page with JavaScript. [That - of course - isn't entirely](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/What_is_JavaScript#so_what_can_it_really_do) true but you can't change a totally different page just like that, you get the point.

You can, however, change the text dynamically like you intend. You could - for example - pass the data [in the URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) and then [access the data with JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams).

Where you redirect the user you can replace `index.html` with for example `index.html?buttontext=hello`.

When that's done, you can edit your page where you want the text to change dynamically. You can fetch the parameters with:

```
let params = new URL(document.location).searchParams;
let buttontext = params.get("buttontext");
```

You can snatch your text now, but your way of setting the text is also incorrect. `document.getElementsByName` [returns a NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName). You can access this NodeList's first element though, that is most likely your button. Therefore you can set the text with:

```
document.getElementsByName("regbutton")[0].textContent = buttontext
```

**Edit**

Here are some working snippets incorporating these elements:

*1.html*

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a name="regbutton" href="2.html">Register</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<script>
  document.getElementsByName("regbutton")[0].textContent = new URL(document.location).searchParams.get("buttontext");
</script>
```

*2.html*

```html
<input id="RegisterForm">
<button type="button" id="regDirect" onclick="register()">Go</button>

<script>
function register() {
  let name = document.getElementById("RegisterForm").value; // get name from form
  window.location.href = "1.html?buttontext="+name; // redirect to first page
}
</script>
```

Keep in mind that *1.html* won't produce anything of value here, you'll have to make a local copy of the files.

Comment: it didnt work for me i put first code in first html page script and the second on register function

Comment: That's bad news, however, the code provided does work. I've added some examples that I just tested on my machine, see if yours is different in any meaningful way. Hope this helps.